# How to find out the maximum value of absolute error?

Tags: maxima-minima, error-function, linearization

Given $$f(x,y) = x^2-3xy+5,$$ where $$R : |x-2| \leq 0.1, \ |y-1| \leq 0.1$$ 
Now, this function is approximated by a polynomial $$L(x,y) = x-6y+7$$ at the point $(2,1)$.

How to find out the maximum value of an absolute error in $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|f(x,y)-L(x,y)|=|x^2-3xy-x+6y-2|=$$
$$=|(x-2)^2-3(x-2)(y-1)|\leq$$
$$\leq(x-2)^2+3|(x-2)(y-1)|\leq0.01^2+3\cdot0.1\cdot0.1=0.04.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1.9$ and $y=1.1$, which says that $0.04$ it's the answer.

Done!